# Create Jira Sub-Task using Github Workflow

Tags: github, github-actions

When I am doing
`echo The Title of Pull Request is ${{ github.event.pull_request.title }}`
I am getting blank response {0}.

```
on:
  pull_request:
    branches:
      - 'develop'
    paths:
      - '**/migrations/*'

jobs:

  print_title_of_pr:
    runs-on: ubuntu-20.04
    steps:
      - name: Print Title of PR
        env:
          TITLE: ${{ github.event.pull_request.title }}
        run:
          echo The Title of your PR is $TITLE

     - name: Extract Jira Issue Key
       id: extract-jira-issue-key
       run: |
         PR_BODY="${{ github.event.pull_request.body }}"
         JIRA_ISSUE_KEY=$(echo "$PR_BODY" | grep -o -E '[A-Z]+-\d+')
         echo "::set-output name=jira_issue_key::$JIRA_ISSUE_KEY"


      - name: Create Jira Subtask
        env:
          JIRA_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.JIRA_TOKEN }}
        run: |
          JIRA_ISSUE_KEY=${{ steps.extract-jira-issue-key.outputs.jira_issue_key }}
                
          SUBTASK_DATA=$(cat <<EOF
          {
            "fields": {
              "project": {"id": "1000"},
              "issuetype": {
                "name": "Task"
              }
              "parent": {"key": "$JIRA_ISSUE_KEY"},
              "summary": "Migration applied to PostgreSQL",
            }
          }
          EOF
          )
          
          curl \
          -D- \
          -X POST \
          -H "Authorization: Basic $JIRA_TOKEN" \
          --data "$SUBTASK_DATA" \
          -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
          https://bankofloyal.atlassian.net/jira/software/c/projects/BL/issues/
```

This is the jira-ticket.yml file. I am trying to extract the Jira Ticket from the PR title and create a sub task under the extracted ticket, but under the $PR_BODY and ${{ github.event.pull_request.title }} everything is null